# How to test the latency and throughput of an intrinsic function？

Tags: cpu-architecture, intrinsics, avx, amd-processor, microbenchmark

In [Intel's Intrinsic guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html), each function has its own latency and throughput. For example, `_mm256_loadu_ps`:

```
Architecture, Latency, Throughput (CPI)
Alderlake, 7, 0.333333333
Icelake Intel Core, 7, 0.5
Icelake Xeon, 7, 0.56
Sapphire Rapids, 7, 0.333333333
Skylake, 7, 0.5
```

I want to perform the same test on AMD machines for comparison.
Is any method or benchmark to test the latency and throughput of intrinsic functions?

Especially for latency testing, how can I avoid the impact of out-of-order execution?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the data measured by other people: https://www.uops.info/table.html The table includes data for both Intel and AMD processors. The processors are selected by checkboxes at the top of the table. For example, to view data for my AMD processor, I check “Zen 3” checkbox there.

The `_mm256_loadu_ps` intrinsic compiles into `vmovups` instruction with memory source and register destination. You should check AVX checkbox, enter `VMOVUPS` in the search, and then look for `VMOVUPS (YMM, M256)` line in that table.

Measuring these numbers is relatively hard in practice, but here’s the [Linux tool](https://github.com/andreas-abel/nanoBench) they used to produce the numbers for that table.

Comment: Latency is hard for stuff like loads where the result is in a different "domain" than the source (registers vs. memory) so you can't construct a loop that just involves the instruction you want to test.  Throughput vs. latency is easy to microbenchmark for an instruction like `vaddps`.  uops.info even shows the loop bodies they use for each microbenchmark, so you can see exactly how they tested without digging into `nanobench` yourself.  e.g. https://uops.info/html-tp/ZEN4/VMOVUPS_XMM_M128-Measurements.html shows how they tested throughput and uop on Zen 4.  (click on any number in the table.)